# How to connect to socket with inital bytes

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, networking

I found out that it is possible to get an initial data transferred using EndAccept.

This is from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.endaccept?view=netframework-4.8):

> EndAccept(Byte[], IAsyncResult)
>
> Asynchronously accepts an incoming connection attempt and creates a
>   new Socket object to handle remote host communication. This method
>   returns a buffer that contains the initial data transferred. C#

How can i send this initial bytes? BeginConnect doesnt give me the option. Is there an other methode I can use?

Answer (score 1):

When using the .NET `Socket` API, it is important to keep in mind that this API is *not* native to .NET. It's a wrapper around the Windows Winsock 2 API, which itself is a Windows implementation of the original [Berkeley sockets API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets). This means that there may be features available at the underlying network level that are not necessarily exposed by the .NET API.

Furthermore, it's important to keep in mind that the `Socket` class offers multiple ways to accomplish the same thing. In particular, the `Socket.Connect()` method is not the only mechanism which can be used to create a connection. There is also the `Socket.ConnectAsync()` method, which uses [`SocketAsyncEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs) to provide state for the socket operations, including the connection request, and this data structure *does* provide a means for the client requesting the connection to also provide a buffer of data to be sent.

Even without that `Socket` method, the remote endpoint may not be using .NET's API for making the connection request. Other socket APIs, such as the [`WSAConnect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaconnect) function in Winsock 2, provide a mechanism for the client to include a buffer of data to transmit along with the connection request.

I doubt that you will ever find this data present in the scenario described by the other answer. I.e. if the client makes the connection request separately from any actual send operation, the subsequently sent data won't be included in the connection request. This is because the client cannot send data on the socket until the connection request has completed, which it cannot until the server calls `EndAccept()`. Any data that is delivered along with the `EndAccept()` *must* be provided as an integral part of the original connection request.

You are correct that the synchronous `Socket.Connect()` method doesn't provide a way to do this, but there are other connection mechanisms available, including `Socket.ConnectAsync()`, as well as the non-.NET socket APIs, which do allow for a buffer of data to be included as part of the connection request. It is those data which would be received by the server as part of the `EndAccept()` method call.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you call [BeginAccept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginaccept?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_BeginAccept_System_Int32_System_AsyncCallback_System_Object_) with one of the two overloads that waits for the initial block of data to be sent, then the corresponding [EndAccept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.endaccept?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_EndAccept_System_Byte____System_Int32__System_IAsyncResult_) will provide that block of data.  If you call that overload, it means on the server side, the API call that is accepting the client doesn't complete until the client has sent some data.  I guess this is more efficient in your server code so that you don't wake up until there's some useful data to go along with the client that you've accepted.  This can save you context switches in huge-scale servers and improve efficiency.

If you just call the overload of [BeginAccept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginaccept?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_BeginAccept_System_AsyncCallback_System_Object_) that does **not** ask to wait for initial data, then the corresponding [EndAccept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.endaccept?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_EndAccept_System_IAsyncResult_) will not provide any initially transferred data.

This is evident in the [documentation for AcceptEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nf-mswsock-acceptex) (which is the function that is [called internally by BeginAccept](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,5418)) in the following excerpt:

> If a receive buffer is provided, the overlapped operation will not complete until a connection is accepted and data is read.

So the answer to your question "How can I send this initial bytes?" is technically just have the client "send".